# Widgets of layout are shown incorrect in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I am using RecyclerView to represent some data. This is how data should be displayed:

[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSd79.png)

[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT9Mu.png)

I am sorry for no being able to upload images.
The XML code I am using to layout widgets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">





    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/tvId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Some text"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Some text"

    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Some text"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Some text"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Some text"

        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scan"
        android:id="@+id/scanButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

I do not seem to be changing the layout parameters programatically, what can be the reason it is not represented correctly as in the preview in the IDE? Thank you

Comment: remove `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: change ... inflate(layout,null) to inflate (layout, parent, false) and share your code especially inflater part

Comment: @BurakKarasoy it helped, thank you, if you would like to make an answer, I will gladly accept it as the right one.

Comment: @bekabot I'm glad it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 change ... inflate(layout,null) to
 inflate (layout, parent, false) this because it needs parent's layoutparams
```

**parent (second parameter of inflate method):**

Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (**if attachToRoot is true**),

or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (**if attachToRoot is false.**)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html